# What does the "static" assumption mean?

Tags: public-key, terminology, hardness-assumptions

We can prove the security of a cryptographic scheme in standard model and non-standard model.

Standard models like using some computational assumptions, on the other hand, non-standard models like random oracle, generic group model. Right?

I've seen in a paper [[CGKV18](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/116) ,page 10] the term $\color{blue}{static}$ computational assumption:

---

[image]

---

**The question is**: What does the adjective *static* mean in "static computational assumption"? Do we have non-static computational assumptions? like non-static learning with errors (LWE) (if exists)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static assumptions are in opposition to "$q$-type" assumptions where the length of the problem can vary independently of the security parameter. An example is the $q$-strong Diffie-Hellman problem introduced by [Boneh and Boyen](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/171): given $g,g^\alpha, g^{\alpha^2},\dots,g^{\alpha^q}$, compute $g^{\alpha^{q+1}}$. The problem with this type of assumption is that they [tend to get stronger](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11761679_1) as $q$ increases (weaker assumptions are always preferable). This [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-49096-9_14) has some other references in the introduction if you want to dig deeper.